# Did two and half tribes settled across the Jordan bring Bikkurim?

Tags: tanach, mitzvah, bikkurim-first-fruits, maseches-bikkurim

Two and half tribes (Reuben, Gad and half of Manasseh) were settled on the other side of Jordan and according to Rabbi Yose the Galilean fruits from across the Jordan were not allowed

Bikkurim 1:10

> these bring and recite:[One who brings bikkurim] from Atzeret until the Festival [of Sukkot], from the seven species, from fruit grown on the mountains, or dates grown in the valleys, from oil-olives, and from [produce] from the other side of the Jordan. ***Rabbi Yose the Galilean says: one does not bring [bikkurim] from transjordania, since that is not a land flowing with milk and honey***.

Does this mean the two and half tribes did not bring Bikkurim (first fruits)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a question of actual history, this is hard if not impossible to answer. In terms of standing halakhah however, it accords with the Hakhamim and not R. Yosi ha-Gelili.

As the Rambam wrote in his commentary on the Mishnah:

> ואין הלכה כרבי יוסי הגלילי
>
> And the halakhah does not accord with R. Yosi ha-Gelili

Here is how the Rambam restates the law (H. Bikkurim 2:1):

> מצות עשה להביא ביכורים למקדש; ואין הביכורים נוהגין אלא בפני הבית ובארץ
> ישראל בלבד, שנאמר "ראשית, ביכורי אדמתך, תביא, בית ה' אלוהיך" (שמות
> כג,יט; שמות לד,כו).  ומביאין ביכורים מדבריהם מערי סיחון ועוג ומסוריה,
> שהקונה בסוריה כקונה בירושלים.
>
> It is a positive commandment to bring the first fruits to the Temple.
> [The obligation of] the first fruits applies only while the Temple is
> standing, and only in Eres Yisrael, as [implied by Exodus 23:19]:
> 'Bring of the first ripened fruit of your land to the house of God
> your Lord.' According to Rabbinic decree, one should bring first
> fruits even from the cities of Sihon and Og and from Syria. For a
> person who purchases land in Syria is like one who purchases in
> Jerusalem.

Accordingly they would be obligated to bring it on a rabbinic level, not a biblical level.